# IF Statement in MySQL return Error in phpMyAdmin Query window

Tags: mysql

i just moved from MsSQL languange and learning MySQL.

I try to make an IF statement,

```
set @val1 = 5;
set @val2 = 2;
select @val1, @val2;
if @val1 > @val2 then
set @val3 = 10;
else
set @val3 = 20;
end if;
select @val3 as cTempResult;
```

line 1 to 3 is works, but line 4 to 9 return error as follow

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if @val1 > @val2 then set @val3 = 10' at line 1
```

Does it means IF statement must be executed inside a Procedure or Function only?

Comment: Your assumption is correct.

Comment: @fancyPants thanks for your comment. so, any idea how to design query comment using IF statement without create procedure or function? 
in MsSQL I am able to use a query window to design set of commands (and IF statement) before create a procedure or function.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do

```
SELECT @val1, @val2, IF(@val1 > @val2, 10, 20) AS val3;
```

?

Comment: if you would answer my next question :)
it use comma (,) for "THEN" and "ELSE" right?
how about if i need to use ElseIf several times?

Comment: Then you could use `SELECT CASE WHEN <boolean expression> THEN WHEN <another boolean expression> ELSE END`